# Is this statement true and why?(time complexity)

Tags: time-complexity

I am having a really hard time understanding these so please help me so I may get an example, so I can get a chance to solve more of those. I have tried many different way but none seem to be able to come to a result, my guess is that it is wrong and it is O(n) but I cannot prove it.

```
//Is this statement true and why? 
 square_root(n5) log(square_root(n5)) = O(n3)
```

Comment: you need to format that correctly bud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the steps below would help you deduce the result discussed in the question.

[image]

Because:

[image]

With an appendix:

[image]